# Why do ASP.net controls have to be grouped inside a Panel for them to be separate?

Tags: asp.net, controls, collision

I have a web page with several different types of controls such as Labels, Textboxes, Gridviews and DropDowns. However, I noticed that if I populate the labels from code-behind and they expand over several lines, the labels tend to be shown "behind" the next control, such as a Gridview control. The only way I managed to avoid this was to place the controls I want to keep separate from other controls using the asp:Panel control.

For example:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelSelect" runat="server">
```

.. some controls ...

```
    </asp:Panel>
```

.. another panel with one Label ...

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlLabels" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessages" runat="server" ForeColor="Maroon" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
```

.. and another panel with gridview and other controls ..

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
       <asp:Label ID="lblStudentCount" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Gray"></asp:Label>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvStudents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" CellPadding="2" ShowFooter="true" DataKeyNames="AttendanceID" 
        OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound">
        <Columns>
```

...
etc

So as you can see, for the lblMessages label to expand naturally I have to have it inside a Panel.

If I did not have the Panel controls here to keep things apart, and even if I use `<p>` or `</br>`, I get the lblMessages label showing text physically behind the gridview, which blurs the gridview with the label control and text is un-readable.

So my question is why should controls have to be a in a panel to avoid "control collision"?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use CSS to control the layout of your controls. Without a screen shot, it's hard to provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From IrishChieftain Dec 9 '13 at 23:37**

*You need to use CSS to control the layout of your controls. Without a screen shot, it's hard to provide a solution for you.*